# What does fr<number> mean in guitar music, alongside a ringed number?

Tags: guitar, notation

I've got some sheet music that includes a guitar strumming pattern:

[image: Guitar strumming pattern]

At the top of the page, the specific inversion and octave of the chords are  defined:

[image: Cmaj7 chord]
[image: A chord]
[image: E chord]

What does the `fr5` and ringed 6 mean under the chord name?

**edit**: and why is this marked as a note and not a strum?

Answer (score 1):

It indicates that you play the A chord at the 5th fret and strum all six strings. With the E chord, you are fret zero (an open chord) and once again strum all six strings.

Comment: Which jibes with the chord drawings. The circled numbers are usually fingerings, but we don't normally expect a musician to have 6 fingers on one hand. I am *guessing* the circled 6 indicates the bass note? So an open C chord might be annotated as "C fr0 (5)" since the chord is usually drawn with a mute on 6.

Comment: Could be.  Wonder why there is no notation for the Cmaj7 chord?

Comment: @mikeford: Only the short-duration A and E chords have these annotations - everything else just seems to defer to the chord diagrams

Comment: What's the note vs slash distinction here, also?

Comment: I really don't know.  It seems like a confusing way of writing out a chord progression.  If you post the whole sheet it would help as taken out of context, it looks very inconsistent.

Comment: @mikeford: I've already violated the terms of use by "printing" the sheet to pdf, and don't feel comfortable sharing larger portions online

Comment: Hmm, I'm actually thinking it might mean play a single note on those frets, on the lowest string

Comment: @Eric:  I think you are correct.  I've never seen it before but it makes sense.